# SAXParseException : Cannot find the declaration of element 'definitions'

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I am totatly new to camunda and DMN. I was trying to run DMN example in spring-boot. [Here is the link](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/dmn-engine/dmn-engine-java-main-method)  of example I am tring to run on my machine.

Here are my pom dependencies,

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camunda.version>7.4.0</camunda.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- camunda DMN Engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.dmn</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-engine-dmn-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${camunda.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.dmn</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-engine-dmn</artifactId>
        <version>${camunda.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run it shows following stacktrace

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'definitions'.
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
>       at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

One thing I did't get is, in resource they have decision schema in xml file and there they have url for [xsd](http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn11.xsd) which is not working.

After some ;) research I found [this](http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/1.0/) link where xsd url is given I tried that but again name space url is not working.

Please, do comment if I am missing something :)

**EDIT**

[Here is Link to my project](https://github.com/prashant-shilimkar/dmn_demo)

Comment: Regarding the XSD: The DMN 1.1 XSD isn't officially release yet. The XSD used by Camunda DMN engine can be found under: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model/blob/master/src/main/resources/DMN11.xsd

Which Camunda Version did you use in your Spring Boot Project?

Comment: Thank you for url. I am using 7.4.0 version. How can I solve my problem. Please do comment.I have edited question with pom dependencies.

Comment: How did you create the DMN file? It doesn't seem to be valid for the DMN 1.1 XSD. Can you attach the DMN XML file?

Comment: I am using the dmn file from the example from git which link I have mentioned in my question. Following is the link for DMN file   https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/dmn-engine/dmn-engine-java-main-method/src/main/resources/org/camunda/bpm/example/dish-decision.dmn11.xml

Comment: The file from the example is valid. Is the example working for you? Can you share a link to your project otherwise I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: @Menski  Here is the link of my project  https://github.com/prashant-shilimkar/dmn_demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you use the Spring [`ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation which is used to import bean definitions. That is why Spring tries to validate the DMN XML file you specified and correctly fails as it isn't in the correct format. Remove this [line](https://github.com/prashant-shilimkar/dmn_demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/DishDecider.java#L17).

Also you have change the namespace of the [dmn file](https://github.com/prashant-shilimkar/dmn_demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/dish-decision.dmn11.xml#L2) it has to be `http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn11.xsd`.

And the path of your [resource loading](https://github.com/prashant-shilimkar/dmn_demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/DishDecider.java#L55) is incorrect as your class inside a package and the DMN file is not. Change it to `InputStream inputStream = DishDecider.class.getResourceAsStream("/dish-decision.dmn11.xml");`.

After these 3 changes your example should work.

Comment: one doubt, I am not good in xml but just curious if I brows xsd url for dmn in browser it does not work. Then how it gets xsd to validate xml?

Comment: The XSD is only validated by the Camunda DMN Model API which has the XSD as a resource. The [one](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-dmn-model/blob/master/src/main/resources/DMN11.xsd) I linked in a previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'definitions'

This error means that reading your XML file (which one ?), there is no `definitions` tag whereas a schema stipulates there should be one.

Comment: Sorry, but I didnot get your answer.Do you mean it didnot find the xml file in resource folder?

Comment: It did find the XML but its content does not match what is expected.