# DMN-02003 Unable to transform decisions Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'definitions'

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am deploying simple dmn file created by camunda modeller (4.2.0, UPDATE same with 4.12.0 Release Date: January 18, 2022):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/MODEL/" xmlns:dmndi="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/DMNDI/" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DC/" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DI/" id="Definitions_0sib65s" name="DRD" namespace="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.2.0">
  <decision id="Decision_1qnsi7h" name="Decision 1">
    <informationRequirement id="InformationRequirement_1n68q12">
      <requiredInput href="#InputData_0cvdsfu" />
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable id="DecisionTable_1o6i63n">
      <input id="Input_1">
        <inputExpression id="InputExpression_1" typeRef="string">
          <text></text>
        </inputExpression>
      </input>
      <output id="Output_1" typeRef="string" />
    </decisionTable>
  </decision>
  <inputData id="InputData_0cvdsfu" />
  <dmndi:DMNDI>
    <dmndi:DMNDiagram>
      <dmndi:DMNShape dmnElementRef="Decision_1qnsi7h">
        <dc:Bounds height="80" width="180" x="160" y="100" />
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="DMNShape_0cj7rh9" dmnElementRef="InputData_0cvdsfu">
        <dc:Bounds height="45" width="125" x="198" y="298" />
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNEdge id="DMNEdge_17tvn8k" dmnElementRef="InformationRequirement_1n68q12">
        <di:waypoint x="261" y="298" />
        <di:waypoint x="250" y="200" />
        <di:waypoint x="250" y="180" />
      </dmndi:DMNEdge>
    </dmndi:DMNDiagram>
  </dmndi:DMNDI>
</definitions>
```

but it fails with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-08043 Exception while performing 'Deployment of Process Application application' => 'Deployment of process archive 'null': ENGINE-22004 Unable to transform DMN resource 'bpmn/diagram_1.dmn'.
...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error: URI=null Line=2: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'definitions'.
```

Deployment is via resource in standard spring boot project with dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This error did come up multiple times on internet:

- On [camunda forum itself](https://forum.camunda.org/t/dmn-02003-unable-to-transform-decisions-from-input-stream/14641) user does not know how/if he solved this issue.
- Other search [result](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/5a311fd6-30af-4fb6-9f57-fdd03a000a16/y) also does not have answer.
- In general looking into "Cannot find the declaration of element" error (f.e. [here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13321178/1651107) ) I do not see any issue with the dmn file - it has default xmlns="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/MODEL/" and also namespace="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" declared correctly AFAIK.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488689/saxparseexception-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-definitions) it is suggested to change the namespace so I used <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20151101/dmn11.xsd" but that does not seem to match xml file created by camunda modeller (cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'informationRequirement') but it seems to helped with 'definitions' element (Not sure why)?.

BPMN files created and deployed same way are working without issues! They are a bit different - ...<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"... but that should be ok in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone like me who's still looking for an answer , all I had to do was to fill the time to live property on the decision Node.
[Check this image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUdoF.png)

Comment: Hello, it would be nice to add details of your code that relates to solution. Not for me but for other users having this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the right for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The DMN standard was upgraded to version 1.3, hence the difference in the namespace. You are using a pretty old model/er version. Try to upgrade.

Your DMN does not contain any column definitons or rules. Please try a complete valid DMN, e.g. one of those:
https://github.com/rob2universe/process-models/tree/master/dmn/dinnerDecision

Comment: Using Camunda Modeller 4.12.0 (Release Date: January 18, 2022) does not resolve this issue.

Comment: Updated answer...